# Windows 8 e-mail verification address cannot be changed when incorrect

Tags: email, windows-8, verification

I mistyped my Google account information when a Win 8 app asked for an e-mail address to send a verification to. The app has no way to let me change the address; it's on a loop. Does anyone know how to get this corrected?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to resolve?

Comment: which app are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Upgrade Assistant ? If yes delete %localappdata%\Microsoft\WebSetup and download  [the Upgrade Assistant once again](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8)